# Can't build React Native after add React-Native-Camera and React-Native-Push-Notification

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-push-notification

My existing project was working fine with

```
"react-native": "0.59.x",
"react-native-camera": "^2.11.2"
```

After I added "react-native-push-notification" to my project =>

```
"react-native": "0.59.x",
"react-native-camera": "^2.11.2",
"react-native-push-notification": "^2.1.0",
```

I encountered several issues, and I fixed them one by one and after add

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

to the ***gradle.properties*** I ended up with an issue in React-Native-Camera

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:compileGeneralDebugJavaWithJavac'
```

I doubt the error occurred because of some version mismatches, but I couldn't find it.
Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2240 did you check this one

Comment: Because of [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2240) thread i added `android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true` to my _gradle.properties_, after that the RNCamera issue came.

Comment: when i search for **android.support.v4.content** my VSCode doesn't give any results, but when i run the project each time it gives a new error related to **android.support.v4.content**. But the issue now is i have to change it in all my libraries.

Comment: I think someone answer your question I never use reactive native by myself

Answer (score 0):

On MacOSX bigsur, for me the problem was really that I had 2 JDK's installed:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V | grep jdk

Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.281.09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_282 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

React Native needs the adoptopenjdk version, so I added to my ~/.bash_profile the adoptopenjdk path as the **JAVA_HOME** environment variable:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home"
```